# How to include another XHTML in XHTML with path info in URL

Tags: jsf-2, header, include, facelets

I will post some pictures to clarify my problem.... i WOULD post pictures but i am not allowed to -.-

If i use a url like

```
localhost:8080/SupervoteWeb/polls
```

everything works fine. The header is displayed correctly.
But for some sites i need the url for passing ids or other attributes.
I have checked if it is because of this parameter passing. This is not the case.

An URL like:

```
localhost:8080/SupervoteWeb/polls[/ enter anything here]
```

always leads to an error where the header is not displayed correctly. 
This is the code of the header. It is placed on every site.

```
 <ui:insert>
    <ui:include src="/protected/header.xhtml" />
</ui:insert
```

By the way: I am using prettyfaces for clean urlmappings.

Can you tell me where this weird behaviour comes from?
If there is any code missing you may need i will post it.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please edit and clarify by posting real code causing the trouble. Are you concretely asking how to use `<ui:include src="/user/#{user.id}" />` while having an `/user.xhtml`?

Comment: I hope, it is better now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved!

The .css was not found - I had relative links to my css files.